# negative space creation inside illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This may sound silly... but i really dnt understand the process that is why am asking. Cause i believe ''Better to ask a question than to remain ignorant''

In logo creation process i observe some famous logos which incorporate artistic presentation of negative space in the design.

But what i really don't get is how the negative space was created..

In the attached photo i created two negative space logos ( just for demonstration)

In one picture the RV is a object with white fill color,

And in another one it has been cut out... and it is hollow.. you can see the sun through the cut-out...

So when a client asks for negative space logo which procedure i should follow? should i draw the negative space shape/object match it with background color  or simply draw the negative space shape and then cut it out?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is much more than only a technical problem in using software.

You have an analog problem with creating a text for a song with perfect rhymes. The rhymes must fit with the composed music. And then there must be a story - interesting and grammatically acceptable regardless all the limitations that the need of rhymes and musical rhythm cause.

Negative space means that the edges of the drawn shapes without specially distorting the shapes too much are a border of a recognizable shape which actually is a hole, but which completes the graphical idea. You may for example need an image which contains three persons. You draw only 2, but do it so cleverly that the 3rd person is formed by the edges of the 2 persons actually drawn.

Simply making a hole to a shape (=X) by subtracting another shape isn't "negative space design" if the created hole is meaningless for X. It should make X more complete.

You should decide which shapes can be relevant and try to invent a way to make one as a negative space. There's no mechanical receipe for fine negative space creations. This is just a place where a talented artist is needed. The rest of us can only make variations of already seen inventions. Some of us surely have the needed capability.

Good luck for your own explorations.

Comment: Thank you so much. that 3 person example speaks volume about the brainstorming.

Answer (score 1):

In printing generally, filling an object white means no ink will be applied in that area, unless you specifically ask for white ink.  White ink is sometimes used in screen printing especially when printing on dark materials, but rarely in lithographic or digital printing which are usually printed on white (or light coloured) substrates. A white fill may also be required if the client wants it to appear on a web page and not show the background through the image.

So, basically unless you are putting some graphic element behind the design which you want to show through the hole, then you don't need to cut it out.

Ultimately, what you choose to do depends on what you/your client wants, and what it is being printed on, which print process is being used, or whether your client wants something in the background to show through or not.

How to cut it out?

If you have a single shape (closed object) on top of another, select both, open the pathfinder, and click on the Minus Front button.  Or alternatively use the Shape Builder tool while holding down <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> as you click to delete a shape(or multiple shapes) inside. The Shape Builder tool is easier to use if the objects are made up of complex objects.

If a client wants such a logo, it's pretty easy to make two versions, one with a white fill and one cut out.

Comment: Alternatively, select both objects and go into menu Object > Compound Path > Make.

Comment: Compound Path > Make will only work properly if there are two objects, as will pathfinder's Minus Front.  The Shape Builder tool would be better for more complex shapes.

Comment: Thank you so much, very wisely explained .@BillyKerr